# Prove that the binomial coefficient is congruent to 0 mod p.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $k$ be an integer such that $0<k<p$. Prove that the binomial coefficient ${p\choose k}\equiv 0\pmod p$.

How would I prove this?

Comment: Consider an expansion of the coefficients into ratios of factorials and see where it leads you.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been asked many times on this site. At least in the context of *Freshman's dream* Did you look for it?

Answer (score 5):

We have

$$(p-k)!k!\binom{p}{k} = p!=p(p-1)!$$
but $\gcd\left(p,(p-k)!k!\right)=1$ so by the [Euclid's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) $p|\binom{p}{k}$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**
$$
\binom{p}{k} = \frac{p!}{(p-k)!k!} = p \cdot \frac{(p-1) \cdot (p-2) \cdots (p-k+1)}{k!}
$$

**Hint$^2$:**
$$
\binom{p}{k} \text{ is an integer, and } p \text{ is prime so } k! \not\mid p
$$

Comment: My post was virtually identical to yours, and at the same time!  :D

Comment: @heropup heh yea I saw right after I posted, so I added a second hint.

Answer (score 2):

There are $p$ chairs arranged uniformly around a circular table. We want to choose  $k$ of them.

We say that two such choices $A$ and $B$ are *equivalent* if $B$ is obtainable from $A$ by a rotation. Since $p$ is prime, if $k$ is different from $0$ or $p$, there are precisely $p$ choices that are equivalent to $A$.

Thus the set of choices of $k$ elements can be divided into families (equivalence classes) each of size $p$. It follows that the number of choices is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\binom pk=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}=\frac{(p-k+1)(p-k+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot \overbrace{(p-1)}^{=p-k+(k-1)}}{1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot k}\cdot p$$

But the above is an integer, and $\;k<p\;$ ...