# Show that if $char(\mathbb{F})$ is prime, then $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall a, b \in \mathbb{F}: (a+b)^{p^k} = a^{p^k} + b^{p^k}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields

> **Theorem**: Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $char(\mathbb{F}) = p$ prime, then $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \forall a, b \in \mathbb{F}:
> > (a+b)^{p^k} = a^{p^k} + b^{p^k}$
>
> Once the case $k=1$ is proven, then you can prove the
>   full theorem by induction. For $k=1$:
>
> Newton's binomium tells us that $(a+b)^p = \sum_{n=0}^p
> > \binom{p}{n}a^nb^{p-n}$
>
> If $n \neq 0$ and $n \neq p$ then $\binom{p}{n} =
>  \frac{p(p-1)...(p-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{N}$  which implies
>   $\binom{p}{n}$ is a multiple of $p$ so that $\binom{p}{n}a^nb^{p-n} =
>  0$.
>
> If $n = 0$ then $\binom{p}{n}a^nb^{p-n} = a^p$
>
> if $n = p$ then $\binom{p}{n}a^nb^{p-n} = b^p$
>
> So that $(a+b)^p = \sum_{n=0}^p \binom{p}{n}a^nb^{p-n} = a^{p} +
>  b^{p}$

I'm not sure about the "If $n \neq 0$ and $n \neq p$ then $\binom{p}{n} = \frac{p(p-1)...(p-n+1)}{n!} \in \mathbb{N}$"

I think it can be shown that the prime factorization of $n!$ is part of the prime factorization of $p(p-1)...(p-n+1)$ but I can not see how.

Comment: It's just the explicit description of the binomial coefficient, which you know in all likelihood, and the binom coefficient must be integral.

Comment: @quid I've always assumed that it was integral but why is that the case.

Comment: The part "which implies $\binom{p}{n}$ is a multiple of $p$" is not justified. You have to use the fact that $p$ is prime (using Euclid' lemma or something like that). See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815393

Comment: It depends how you define things. If you define the binomial coeffcient as the coefficient in the expansion it is a priori clear it is integral as it is the number of relevant terms, but then you need to show the explicit description, so it's true there is something to show. I was just a bit puzzled  you ask this in this context, but then why not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the prime factorisation of $n!\;$ to see that. First,as @quid recalled it, binomial coefficients are  natural numbers, hence the denominator divides the numerator.

Furthermore $\;n!\;$ is a product of factors, each of which is smaller than $p$. Hence none can  divide $p$ since $p$ is prime. Therefore, their product $n!\,$ is coprime with $p$, and divides $p\,\times$ another factor. By Gauß's lemma, it divides this other factor.

*Note:* the characteristic of a field is always $0$ or a prime number.

Comment: But why does it divide $p(p-1)\dots (p-n+1)$ *at all*? I think this is what OP is asking.

Comment: @quid: this point seemed to go without saying. I've added an explanation about it.

Comment: On the one hand I agree. On the other hand, did you see my comment exchange with OP?

Comment: @quid: Sorry, I must say I didn't. I've added due credit for the observation.

Comment: Thanks for that. But my worry was not about the attribution but rather that OP's concern might not yet be addressed. Yet at this point it's likely best to wait for OP to chime in. Maybe it does address their concern after all. In any case, it's a good answer to this type of question.